# Is there a way to pass Class objects in Python between different modules and retain namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Hi guys I have a quick question about classing in Python. I have a script that pulls a list of houses in an area and collects the 
data for each house and saves it in a file.

For brevity, in the example code, we assume that we have already retrieved the `data` by declaring a `list` of `House` objects and the `save_file()` function only prints data:

The `app.py` file is:

```py
from save_data import save_file

class House:
    def __init__(self, year_built, sqft):
        self.year_built = year_built
        self.sqft = sqft


house_one = House('2010', '2340')
house_two = House('2014', '4340')

house_list = [house_one, house_two]

save_file(house_list)
```

The `save_data.py` file is:

```py
def save_file(final_list):
    for house in final_list:
        print(house.year_built)
        print(house.sqft)
```

This works perfectly but I want to know that when I edit `save_data.py` file in my IDE (PyCharm), when I type `house.` it doesn't load the `House` class variables because the `app.py` hasn't run yet. For example, if I type `house` followed by `.` inside the `app.py` file it will show up the class variables.

My actual `House` class has over 25 variables and its hard to remember all the names and it would be very convenient if the IDE could load the names if I just type the `house.` inside the `save_data.py` file.

Is there anyway I can import the House class from the `app.py` file to `save_data.py` file and/or declare `house` inside the code `for house in final_list` of type `House` to gain this functionality?

Comment: PyCharm supports this - if you use type hints (in python 3). Not sure how you can do it with python 2 (and maybe you shouldn't - python2 is EOL in 3 months). Check out mypy + the mypy pycharm plugin, maybe that'll work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response I am going to definitely check it out! I am not sure why I tagged it python-2.7 it should have been python3 which is what I use!

Comment: Thanks again @rdas I was able to accomplish what I needed using type hints in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with type hints as mentioned in comments:

```
from typing import List
from app import House


def save_file(final_list: List[House]):
    for house in final_list:
        print(house.year_built)
        print(house.sqft)
```